# changing image in pygame

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I'm making a game for school that's a mini RPG thing. I have tried to code it so that the image changes, but my code doesn't work. I've looked through many articles, and I have not found a working solution for my case. Have I done something wrong in a specific area, or have I started the code at a completely incorrect angle? Help is greatly appreciated.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

width = 800
height = 600

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('8Bit Adventure Time!')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

finnImg = [pygame.image.load('AdvManRight.png'), pygame.image.load('AdvManLeft.png')]
finnImg_current = finnImg[0]

finnwidth = 115
finnheight = 201

def Finn(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(finnImg_current, (x, y))

def game_loop():

    x = ((width/2) - (finnwidth/2))
    y = ((height/2) - (finnheight/2))


    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        x_change = 0
        y_change = 0

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        Finn(x,y)

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    finnImg_current = finnImg[0]
                    pygame.display.update() #the image is supposed to change here, but nothing happens...
                    x_change = -40
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    finnImg_current = finnImg[1]
                    pygame.display.update() #the image is supposed to change here, but nothing happens...
                    x_change = 40
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y_change = -40
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 40

        x += x_change
        y += y_change

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a global variable `finnImg_current` which is what is being blit to the screen when you call `Finn(x, y)`. But in your game loop you're creating a local variable also called `finnImg_current`. These are different!

To fix the problem you could just type `global finnImg_current` at the top of your function `game_loop`. Also, `pygame.display.update()` should only be called once in your game loop, most preferably in the end of it.

Try to follow the PEP8 conventions when writing code, it makes it easier for other programmer to read it. Basically, variable and functions should be named with `lowercase_and_underscore`, and classes with `CamelCase`. Try not to mix these because it'll be confusing.